# Using JNI or some other tool, is it possible to achieve Reflection of C code in Java?

Tags: java, c, json, struct, java-native-interface

Hello and thanks for taking the time to help, much appreciated.

I have many populated structs written in C. I need to convert them to JSON where the name of the variable is the key, and its value is the value. From what I have researched so far, there is no optimal way to achieve this, and it looks like a loop for each struct will need to be hard coded to obtain a JSON result.

However, it appears that using Reflection (not supported by C), each of the objects can be accessed at run-time in a way where making a JSON string with a loop would be possible.

Is it possible to use Java reflection using JNI or some other tool to solve this problem, and allow access to structs at runtime?

Comment: No, that's not possible because the type information is missing after compilation.

Comment: Thank you for your response. What if the types are not needed. Just the name of the variable and the value assigned to it? For example: struct Test{int age;} Test test; test.age = 5; The desired JSON would be {"age":"5"}

Comment: The variable names are missing too, it's just machine code.

Comment: Oh I see.. Darn, thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Surely if you know it is a C struct, you have, at least, a C header. So, try SWiG. You might be able to initialize a Java array of struct values and use a JSON serializer over the Java array, thereby avoiding writing loops and such just for serialization. (But, no, you wouldn't be able to do that with a struct that hasn't been invented yet, as you could with reflection.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: the fact that a concept (reflection; and *meta* data being available at run time within java class files) exists in one language ... and the fact that one language (Java) has a concept to call (or be called) binaries build from C doesn't mean that this first concept is magically available on the C side. You know, having a bridge over some river doesn't help you to move a building located on the one shore to the other side.

It might be more reasonable to think about building some kind of parser that analyses your C code; and that derives the JSON information from that source (code).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Makes sense. I have started to make a parser and I have it where it finds all the structs and stores the variable names. However, I am not sure how I can optimally get the values associated with each of those variables without making a loop for each struct. Any suggestions?

Comment: @JaredSmith I think that deserves a new question.

Comment: I was worried about asking it, It seems like the type of question that will get marked down, and people will yell at me.. haha :/

Comment: @JaredSmith Which is somehow correct. You should only write up a new question after doing some research/coding experiments.

Comment: I have been looking into this problem for awhile. All the solutions involve modifying the structs to use boast. However with the amount of structs, that solution is not optimal. The source code for these was written years ago.

Comment: The more I look into it, the more it seems hard coding a loop for each struct will be the only way.

Comment: Sounds so. On the other: if that code is really that old; probably it isn't changed all the time; so biting the bullet once might still be the cost-efficient solution.

Comment: Seems so.. However I did come up with a solution. What are your thoughts on it. After parsing all the header files, and writing the struct name and all its field per line to a file. I then read that file line by line  and generated the C code and wrote the results to a file. Then I just added that C code to the end of the code and was able to obtain a JSON result.